# PostgreSQL gem pg was unable to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My DB is PostgreSQL.I am on CENTOS.... While installing the pg gem I received the following error. I reinstalled to clear my YAML problem also, which didn't work, but it is just a warning. My main problem is the installation of the pg gem:

```
[root@vdimc04 ~]# gem install pg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

I also tried with the following command, but to no use:

```
 gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: You should find and fix the YAML issue too. YAML is used to process configuration files and is very useful to Ruby.

Comment: i have installed YAML from the link http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4 tar.gz

Comment: can u say command to uninstall ruby..
i used rpm -e ruby1.9.3-p327 to uninstall but after uninstalling, if i type 'ruby -v' it shows the version name.. Does it mean is it uninstalled properly or not i dont know...

Comment: Are you using RVM or ruby via `yum`? If RVM, I have my whole CentOS RVM, Ruby, Rails, PostgreSQL recipe at hand.

Comment: i installed ruby by downloading the ruby1.9.3-p327 package and installed through commands ./configure , make , make install.. thats it.. but when i uninstalled through rpm -e ruby1.9.3p327 is shows that it is uninstalled but if i type ruby -v after uninstalling it shows the version name....

Comment: @PavanKumar you installed ruby from source. That means that you can't use rpm or yum to uninstall (since to them, ruby _hasn't_ been installed). Try `make uninstall` if the source buildfile supports that. Afterwards, use RVM (cleaner, and more cross-platform than `yum`) to reinstall ruby, rails and pg gems.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael please send me the recipy that you had..
My ID: ch_pavankumar@sify.com
I am so thankful to u if u send me that process.......

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I got the same error on Centos. By googling I found two commands to use:

1. `yum install postgresql-libs` -- It gave me message saying, its already installed.
2. `yum install postgresql-devel` -- It solved my error related to `pg_config` for installing the 'pg' .gem.

Hope it helps :)

apos wrote: on Ubuntu 14.04 install:

1. `apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.3 libpq-dev`

Comment: i dont have many reputations to upvote.. but after getting sure i will....
and i have a doubt.. i ave edited database.yl to postgres..
But while i am executing  'rails server' it shows ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished 

How t solve this....

Comment: Changing adopter name is not enough, DB driver configurations are different for different databases. You need to change all the properties according to the database.

Comment: development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: database name/development.postgresql
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  passowrd: password
  host: 192.168.1.101 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: database name
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  passowrd: password

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production.postgresql
  pool: 5
  username: db_test_user
  passowrd: password

Is the above mentioned database.yml file is correct or not?? i dont know. please go through that

Comment: i have installed 'gem pg' for ruby

Comment: Using AWS Cloud 9 Linux:

`sudo yum install postgresql-libs`

then:

`sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

then:

`bundle install`

Answer (score 20):

Here's my recipe for getting PostgreSQL, RVM, Ruby, Rails all up and running on CentOS

## PostgreSQL

First, follow the instructions on http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation to get PostgreSQL installed:

`sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[base]
exclude=postgresql*

[updates]
exclude=postgresql*
```

Get the latest PGDG RPM file (for your platform/architecture), for example:

```
curl -O http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-latest-x86_64/pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
```

Then

```
sudo rpm -ivh pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y postgresql92-server postgresql92-devel
```

Initialize the database:

```
sudo service postgresql-9.2 initdb
```

Configure `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/postgresql.conf` and `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf` as needed.

Start PostgreSQL server:

```
sudo service postgresql-9.2 start
```

## RVM

```
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum -y install zlib zlib-devel sqlite-devel httpd curl-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel mlocate man libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel readline-devel
```

Note, *NOT* as root:

```
\curl -L get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

Logout and back on. Afterwards, `which rvm` should reply with `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm` and `type rvm|head -1` should say `rvm is a function`.

## Ruby + Rails

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
gem install rake
gem install rails
```

## PostgreSQL gem

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
```

The `--with-pg-config` is somehow needed with my latest installation of CentOS, otherwise, `gem install pg` can't find `pg_config`. YMMV, but if you follow all the above to the letter (which I've done enough times in the past few months) just let me know if anything trips you up.

Comment: can u give me the steps to start the rails program.. as i was new to this i dont know how to connect the program to database like in java we are having jar files, but here i donnt know hot to connect to database and also in IDE which folder we have to start writing the code.......

Comment: @Alistairsrael now thanks for ur recepie yaar.. now the new problem is: 
i have installed postgres libraries and everything.. and pg gem also.. now the problem is it is not connecting to postgres database. Receiving the ERROR AS ACTIVE RECORD : CONNECTIN NOT ESTABLILSHED

Comment: No, unless you want the server to bind to ports < 1024.

Comment: @Alistairlsrael..ok.. Thank u .. Thanks a lot.. My sever is working fine.. I made some changes to pg_hba.conf file.. Its working

Comment: This is a great resource for painful processes! Thank you.

Comment: gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config was the key thing for me. Except for pgsql-9.4 on Fedora 21.

Comment: Because this answer keeps getting upvoted, I feel obligated to share my new "workflow" for installing, for example, PostgreSQL on CentOS/RHEL/Fedora or Debian/Ubuntu. First, [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/#install-using-the-repository). Then just `docker run postgres` (with all the requisite parameters).

Answer (score 6):

try installing libpq package by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

That package helps with pg gem and you should be fine after that :)

Comment: thank u for response..but i am on centos. in that sudo apt-get will not work –

Answer (score 5):

Try This, the answer is not mine but it worked for me. Remember to point to where your Postgres.app application is:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Then do

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libdbd-pg-ruby1.8
```

then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pg
```

for CentOS please read the below link..

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation

To install pg in centOS

```
run this commands

bundle config build.pg 

gem install pg -v '0.12.0'
```

Comment: thank u for response..but i am on centos. in that sudo apt-get will not work

Comment: YUM is to install postgresql..but i already have postgres. but the gem file of pg is not installing..

Comment: hi. again i have updated my answer to install pg gem. Please try this.

Comment: same error yaar... it started fetching the file.later same error repeats

Comment: bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

Comment: try the above and then gem install pg -v '0.12.0'

Comment: While i am running this command "bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config" error is: Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: try this "bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config" . i think this will work. we have to mention the path correctly.

Comment: check where the libpq-fe.h file is installed. tell me the path

Comment: type this command it will show the path of the file.  locate libpq-fe.h

Comment: bash: locate command not found.. I used the command 'find . -name libpq-fe.h
'

Comment: finally u try this ..      gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/usr/pgsql-9.0/lib --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config

Comment: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'

Comment: Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
[root@vdimc04 ~]#

Comment: Vijay i was so thankful to u but when i tried using yum list | grep installed | grep ruby 
no list was generated...

i think yum is used to list only the sofwares that are installed through yum only..

Comment: but when i run ruby -v it gives as:

[root@vdimc04 ~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i686-linux]

Comment: i have downloaded the ruby pack and installed through the commands like ./configure, make, make install

then it is installed

but after uninstalling through rpm -e ruby 1.9.3-p327 if i type ruby -v it again gives me the result..

what a wonder it is......

Comment: perfect!. bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 1):

Try to install postgresql server and corresponding libraries.
Then install the pg gem. Then it will work for u

Comment: server has already installed.. and corresponding libraries means?? can u give any commands to execute???

Comment: i have installed postgres librariess and everything.. and pg gem also.. now the problem is it is not connecting to postgres database.

Receiving the ERROR AS ACTIVE RECORD : CONNECTIN NOT ESTABLILSHED

Answer (score 0):

First install

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Next install

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then install `gem install pg`

Comment: thank u for ur response..I am on centos.. sdo apt-get will not work here

Comment: Login as the root user then Use 'yum' instead of 'sudo apt-get'.

Comment: Just check this link for installing "yum' and "postgresql" http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides and then try gem install pg .. May it will useful for u.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is before pg gem was already installed.. but it is not loading to bundle..
Now the solution is:
when we are declaring a new application like 'rails new Demo' we have to include

'--database=postgresql'. so now the total command is: 'rails new Demo --database=postgresql'

Then the pg gem file will gets to bundle..

In bundle only one gem will gets store . either pg gem or sqlite3 gem..

Now edit the database.yml file accordingly..
thats it

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I tried to install all dependencies, but all is useless. In the end, I had a try to use PostgreSQL9.3, not PostgreSQL9.4, and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS Cloud 9 Linux:

`sudo yum install postgresql-libs`

then:

`sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

then:

`gem update --system`

if needed, then:

`gem install bundler` (Bundler 2.0)

then:

`bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 and pg gem version 1.4.0 which requires postgres version greater or equal 9.3:

```bash
yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh
yum search -y postgresql13-devel
yum install -y libpqxx-devel postgresql13-devel
ln -sf /usr/pgsql-13/bin/pg_config /usr/bin/pg_config

gem install pg:1.4.0
```