# Cant install pg gem in centos7 with Postgres9.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos7

When I trying to solve a problem, always downgrade the version of postgresql.

- vagrant
- centos7
- postgreSQL 9.6
- ruby 2.4.2
- rails 5.1.3

**install postgreSQL(user:root)**

```
yum install -y https://yum.postgresql.org/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
yum install -y postgresql96-server postgresql96-contrib postgresql96-devel postgresql96
psql --version => 9.6
```

**install ruby(user:vagrant)**

```
sudo yum -y install gcc-c++ glibc-headers openssl-devel readline libyaml-devel readline-devel zlib zlib-devel git
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

**install rails**

```
touch Gemfile
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
bundle exec rails new progect_name --skip-bundle -d postgresql

cd project_name
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Error

> "gcc -E -I/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.4.$
>   conftest.c:3:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory

I found an article "**gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_config**" could solve this, but nothing change.
Running "sudo yum -y install postgresql-devel" solve pg gem error, but postgreSQL versions change 9.6 to 9.2.23.

Comment: have you tried this `bundle config --local build.pg '--with-pg-config=/bin/none'` and then `bundle install`

Comment: Thank you for your support. I finally made it !!

Comment: Can you please share your solution here. If it worked with the command, i mentioned in my comment, I can add it as answer and we can close this.

Comment: Mike what was you fix that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

[PostgreSQL gem pg was unable to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702417/postgresql-gem-pg-was-unable-to-install?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Solved for me

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this error, you can try:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```